# Get first fulfilled promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

If I have two promises A and B, only one of which will succeed, how can I get whichever one fulfills successfully? I'm looking for something similar to `Promise.race`, but which will return only the first promise that fulfills. I'm using promises from ES6.

Comment: You are looking for `Promise.any` ([Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html), [Creed](https://github.com/briancavalier/creed#any--iterable-promise-e-a--promise-e-a), [WinJS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229660.aspx), …)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Invert the polarity of the promises, and then you can use `Promise.all`, because it rejects on the first rejected promise, which after inversion corresponds to the first fulfilled promise:

```js
const invert  = p  => new Promise((res, rej) => p.then(rej, res));
const firstOf = ps => invert(Promise.all(ps.map(invert)));

// Utility routines used only in testing.
const wait    = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(ms), ms));
const fail    = f  => Promise.reject(f);
const log     = p  => p.then(v => console.log("pass", v), v => console.log("fail", v));

// Test.
log(firstOf([wait(1000), wait(500) ]));
log(firstOf([wait(1000), fail("f1")]));
log(firstOf([fail("f1"), fail("f2")]));
```

This will return the value of the first fulfilled promise, or if all reject, an array of rejection reasons.

Comment: Clever.  This isn't the first time the concept of inverting shows to be useful in promise-land.

Comment: @jfriend00 Right, this technique was shown in at least one other answer on SO that I can't track down, not original.

Comment: This is a clever hack.

Comment: @torazaburo, you've possibly seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243378/execute-multiple-tasks-asynchronously-and-return-first-successful-result-in-java/21273983#21273983)

Comment: Can also be written as `Promise.prototype.invert()` and `Promise.any()` - https://jsfiddle.net/akvewbje/

Answer (score 8):

### ES2021 / ES12 - Promise.any

`Promise.any` - first **fulfilled** Promise wins.

```
const promiseA = Promise.reject();
const promiseB = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'succeed'));

const promises = [promiseA, promiseB];


Promise.race(promises).then((value) => console.log(value)); // rejected promise

Promise.any(promises).then((value) => console.log(value)); // "succeed"
```

Notice that `any` is ignoring the first rejected promise - `promiseA` because `promiseB` is being resolved

If all of the given promises are rejected, then the returned promise is rejected.

---

**This is [finished proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md) and it's scheduled for ES2021 (expected to be released in June 2021)**

Answer (score 4):

If you want the first promise that resolves successfully and you want to ignore any rejections that come before that, then you can use something like this:

```
// returns the result from the first promise that resolves
// or rejects if all the promises reject - then return array of rejected errors
function firstPromiseResolve(array) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (!array || !array.length) {
            return reject(new Error("array passed to firstPromiseResolve() cannot be empty"));
        }
        var errors = new Array(array.length);
        var errorCntr = 0;
        array.forEach(function (p, index) {
            // when a promise resolves
            Promise.resolve(p).then(function(val) {
                // only first one to call resolve will actually do anything
                resolve(val);
            }, function(err) {
                errors[index] = err;
                ++errorCntr;
                // if all promises have rejected, then reject
                if (errorCntr === array.length) {
                    reject(errors);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I don't see how you can use `Promise.race()` for this because it simply reports the first promise to finish and if that first promise rejects, it will report a rejection.  So, it is not doing what you asked in your question which is to report the first promise that resolves (even if some rejections finished before it).

FYI, [the Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) has both `Promise.some()` and `Promise.any()` which can handle this case for you.

Comment: You should use `p.then(…, …)` instead of `p.then(…); p.catch(…)` to avoid unhandled rejections

Comment: @Bergi -Where is there an unhandled rejection?

Comment: If `p` rejects, the result of `p.then(…)` is a promise that is rejected and never handled.

Comment: @Bergi - Uh, it's handled by `p.catch()` just fine in the context of this code.  What actual problem could occur in this code?  Unless you think calling `resolve(val)` could throw, I don't see an unhandled rejection here.  Or are you just referring to a promise library might issue a warning (even though there is no actual problem in the code)?

Comment: I said *result*. In `q = p.then(…); p.catch(…)` the rejection of `p` is handled (twice), yes, but the rejection of `q` is never handled and as such globally reported, which is wrong.

Comment: @Bergi - Except there is no way that `q` can reject in this code unless `resolve(val)` could throw.  I guess you're making a theoretical observation, not one that could actually happen.  I can chain the `.catch()`.

Comment: No, it's a very practical problem. Just try to run it in an ES7 environment. `q` will reject if `p` rejects, the handler isn't even invoked. No, please don't use the `p.then(…).catch(…)` antipattern, just do `p.then(…, …)`

Comment: You still have not explained how this is a real problem.  Or why `p.then(fn1).catch(fn2)` is an anti-pattern.  In my book, `p.then(fn1).catch(fn2)` is generically safer than `p.then(fn1, fn2)`, because it catches exceptions in fn1.  And, what does ES7 have to do with this?  You're making some unexplained objections.

Comment: ES7 specifies how unhandled rejections work, and they did incorrectly fire with your original code. Your book is right about `.then(…).catch(…)`, but it says *generically*, and this is a specific situation where we want `.then(…, …)` (we never want `fn1` *and* `fn2` to be called both) - it's not totally wrong as your `fn1` never throws, but it is cleaner, more efficient and would properly report if you made a mistake (like a typo) in `fn1`.

Comment: @Bergi - Can you point to some article about what changes for unhandled rejections in ES7 and how that was relevant here?  I changed the code to `.then(fn1, fn2)` though it seems like it was for theoretical objections only, not something that could actually occur in this code.

Comment: Dunno whether there's a good article, it's just that ES7 codifies how/which unhandled rejections are reported to the host environment (and ES6 didn't). Nothing really changed for libraries that already supported it. A web search pointed me to https://github.com/domenic/unhandled-rejections-browser-spec/ though

Comment: Another problem I just came across: this doesn't work on empty arrays, it would produce a forever hanging promise instead of rejecting immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and gave it a go. You learn a lot by trying these problems yourself!

1. The accepted answer is very elegant but uses `Promise.all` which takes the fun for someone learning Promises; also a bit hard to follow imo.
2. `jfriend00`'s answer is similar to mine but has that logic that goes beyond the Promises fundamentals which is most important here.

I have made use of those nice helper functions present on the accepted answer:

```js
function firstPromise(promiseL, promiseR) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        promiseL.then(l => {
            resolve(l);
        }).catch(error => null);

        promiseR.then(r => {
            resolve(r);
        }).catch(error => null);


        promiseL.catch(errorL => {
            promiseR.catch(errorR => {
                reject(errorL + errorR);
            })
        })
    })
}

const wait = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(ms), ms));
const log = p => p.then(v => console.log("pass", v), v => console.log("fail", v));


log(firstPromise(wait(1000), wait(500)));
log(firstPromise(wait(1000), Promise.reject("Bar")));
log(firstPromise( Promise.reject("Foo"), wait(500)));
log(firstPromise( Promise.reject("Foo"), Promise.reject("Bar")));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 //example 1
    var promise_A = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // выполнить что-то, возможно, асинхронно…
        setTimeout(function(){

            return  resolve(10);
            //return reject(new Error('ошибка'))
        },10000)
    });

    var promise_B = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // выполнить что-то, возможно, асинхронно…

        setTimeout(function(){
            return  resolve(100);
        },2000)
    });


/*
 //[100,10]
 Promise.all([
  promise_A,promise_B
 ]).then(function(results){
  console.log(results)
 });
*/

 //100
 Promise.race([
  promise_A,promise_B
 ]).then(function(results){
  console.log(results)
 });
```

Comment: This will return either promise that resolves or rejects, not the first promise that fulfills.

Comment: What's up with the comments in Cyrillic?