# Javascript: how to pass additional variables to a promise .catch function

Tags: javascript, variables, promise

I have found out how to pass additional variables to the promise .then function by using Promise.all. But how can I pass these variables to the .catch function?

My abstracted code:

```
// global variable url
var url = [url1, url2, url3];

for (i = 0, i < url.length, i++) {
    // run a promise.all to pass some additional variables to the next .then
    Promise.all([xhr(url[i]), i]).then(function([response, i]) {
        // do something with the response and variable i
        alert(url[i] + " responded: " + response);

    }).catch(function(e) {
        // I need variable i also to be available here!
        alert(url[i] + " failed to respond");

    });
}

function xhr(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // xmlhttprequest with url
        // resolves with the response
        // or rejects with an error message

    });
}
```

This is just a very abstract code to explain that I need variable i also to be available in the .catch function.

How to achieve this?

EDIT:

In response to the answers and my comments to them, here is my complete code with using `let` in the for loop. I think now it is a very neat use of promises to search different search engines in parallel and use the first useful hit.
I use `Promise.any` - an inverted `Promise.all` - to get the first resolved promise from an array of promises. And I use the for loop to prepare the promises for the Promise.any. nzbDonkeySettings is a global variable with my settings:

```
// modifiy the promise prototype to add function "any"
// from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940152/get-first-fulfilled-promise
Promise.prototype.invert = function() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => this.then(rej, res));
};
Promise.any = function(ps)  {
    return Promise.all(ps.map((p) => p.invert())).invert();
};

// function to search and download the nzb file
function searchNZB(nzbHeader) {

    // prepare the promises for all search engines
    var getNZB = []; // the promise array
    for (let i = 0; i < nzbDonkeySettings.searchengines.length; i++) {
        if (nzbDonkeySettings.searchengines[i].active) { // but only for "active" search engines
            getNZB[i] = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

                // first search for the nzb header
                var nzbSearchURL = nzbDonkeySettings.searchengines[i].searchURL.replace(/%s/, encodeURI(nzbHeader));
                var options = {
                    "url": nzbSearchURL,
                    "responseType": "text",
                    "timeout": 20000
                };
                xhr(options).then(function(response) {
                    // if we have a response, check if we have a result
                    var re = new RegExp(nzbDonkeySettings.searchengines[i].searchPattern, "i");
                    if (re.test(response)) {
                        // if we have a result, generate the url for the nzb file
                        var nzbDownloadURL = nzbDonkeySettings.searchengines[i].downloadURL.replace(/%s/, response.match(re)[nzbDonkeySettings.searchengines[i].searchGroup]);
                        // and download the nzb file
                        var options = {
                            "url": nzbDownloadURL,
                            "responseType": "text",
                            "timeout": 120000
                        };
                        xhr(options).then(function(response) {
                            // if we have a response, check if it is a nzb file
                            if (response.match(/<nzb.*>/i)) {
                                // if it is a nzb file, resolve with the nzb file
                                resolve(response);
                            } else {
                                // if it is not a nzb file, reject
                                reject(new Error(nzbDonkeySettings.searchengines[i].name + ": " + "the downloaded file is not a valid nzb file"));    
                            }
                        }).catch(function(e) {
                            // if the download failed, reject
                            reject(new Error(nzbDonkeySettings.searchengines[i].name + ": " + "an error occurred while trying to download the nzb file"));  
                        });
                    } else {
                        // if we have no result, reject
                        reject(new Error(nzbDonkeySettings.searchengines[i].name + ": " + "no nzb file found"));
                    }   
                }).catch(function(e) {
                    // if we have no response, reject
                    reject(new Error(nzbDonkeySettings.searchengines[i].name + ": " + "an error occurred while searching for the nzb file"));   
                });

            });
        }
    }

    // return a promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        // lets "race" the promises and get the result from the first resolved promise
        Promise.any(getNZB).then(function(nzbFile) {
            // resolve with the nzbFile
            resolve(nzbFile);
        }).catch(function(e) {
            // if we have no results, reject
            reject(new Error("no search engine returned any usable result"));   
        });     

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `let` like this:

```
for (let i = 0, i < url.length, i++) {
```

`let` creates a separate variable `i` for each iteration of the `for` loop so even though the `for` loop has continued to run while your `xhr()` requests are running, each invocation of the loop will still have access to its own copy of `i`.

---

Also, there's no reason to use `Promise.all()` at all inside the loop.  You only have one `xhr()` promise for each iteration of the loop:

```
// global variable url
var url = [url1, url2, url3];

for (i = 0, i < url.length, i++) {
    // run a promise.all to pass some additional variables to the next .then
    xhr(url[i]).then(function([response, i]) {
        // do something with the response and variable i
        alert(url[i] + " responded: " + response);

    }).catch(function(e) {
        // I need variable i also to be available here!
        alert(url[i] + " failed to respond");

    });
}
```

Now, if you wanted to know when all the `xhr()` calls were done, you could do this:

```
// global variable url
var url = [url1, url2, url3];

Promise.all(url.map((u, i) => {
    return xhr(u).catch(err => {
        console.log(u + " failed to respond");
        return null;
    });
})).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: WOW! This is so simple and I even do not need the Promise.all trick anymore! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really fond of the idea of adding extra data to promises in this way. You can simply restructure your code to make use of `forEach` and scoping to reach the desired effect:

```
const urls = [url1, url2, url3];
urls.forEach(url => {
    xhr(url)
        .then(response => alert(url + "responded: " + response))
        .catch(() => alert(url + "failed to respond"))
})
```

Comment: Thanks also for your answer, but my actual code is much more complicated then my abstract example (see my edited question) and I don't think that .forEach would help me to simplify the code.

Answer (score 1):

This might be another way to solve your problem;

```js
var apiCall = url => new Promise((v,x) => Math.random() < 0.67 ? v(`some data from ${url}`) : x("Oops..!")),
    urls    = ["url1","url2","url3"],
    ps      = urls.map((u,i) => apiCall(u).then(v => console.log(`Result from API call # ${i+1} is ${v}`))
                                          .catch(e => console.log(`Received Error ${e} from API call ${i+1}`)));
```