# Get first fulfilled promise in RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

Similar to [Get first fulfilled promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940152/get-first-fulfilled-promise) but in RxJS

If I have two promises A and B, only one of which will succeed, how can I get whichever one fulfills successfully? Some of the promises will have rejection as well. Only the successful promise is needed.

I'm looking for something similar to Promise.race, but which will return only the first promise that fulfills. I'm using promises from RxJS6.

Comment: "I'm using promises from RxJS6" — do you mean that you have Observables? Or you're wrapping promises into Observables?

Answer (score 0):

RxJS has [race](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/race) also:

```
import {race} from 'rxjs'

race(promiseA, promiseB).subscribe(result => console.log('winner is ' + result))
```

Comment: does it only considers successful promise as the winner, not the rejected ones?

Comment: no.  It works just like Bluebird's Promise.race.  As soon as any of the promises (or observables) resolves or rejects, that result will be delivered to your subscriber and other results will be ignored.

Comment: @user1595858 if you need only successful results -- pipe a [catchError](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/catch/) that will suppress an error to each source, e.g.: `race( a$.pipe( catchError(()=>NEVER) ),   b$.pipe( catchError(()=>NEVER) ) )`. Though a bit more complex solution is needed to handle a situation if **all** of your sources fail.