# Make Promise.race finish only when one is successful

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have three asynchronous functions that return an object. If one of the functions are not successful, they return an empty object. The issue is that if I try to Promise.race these functions, one of the not successful functions may finish first and have an empty object return. My Promise code looks like this:

```
let product = await Promise.race([
        get_info_1(code),
        get_info_2(code),
        get_info_3(code)
    ])
```

Is it possible to stop one of the asynchronous get_info functions from running without stopping the Promise.race? Or could I somehow tell Promise.race to wait until the returned object contains some information?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to retrieve the data from the first promise that resolves successfully?

Comment: @Rengers Yes, that is a better way to phrase it.

Comment: You're looking for `Promise.any` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any). This is still experimental and perhaps not supported in your environment. In that case you can use a polyfill.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first fulfilled promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940152/get-first-fulfilled-promise)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the rejected `Promise` never complete

```js
const never_resolve = new Promise(() => {}) 
{
  (async function() {
    let product = await Promise.race([
      Promise.reject(1).catch(_ => never_resolve),
      Promise.resolve(2).catch(_ => never_resolve),
      Promise.reject(3).catch(_ => never_resolve)
    ])
    console.log(product)
  })()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promise.any](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any).

```
const promise1 = Promise.reject(0);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'quick'));
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'slow'));

const promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3];

Promise.any(promises).then((value) => console.log(value));

// Expected output: "quick"
```