# search node in a tree using recursive javascript promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, tree, promise

I am stuck in Javascript promise based program and not able to figure out how to get it to return the right value, in a promise format.

Given an Tree API that returns children of a node as PROMISE. Eg:

```
tree.getChildren('/2/4')
.then(function (nodes) {    
    console.log(nodes); // logs 7,8,9 as children of node 4
}
```

using `tree.getChildren` method, the `searchNode` method should recursively try to look for `searchValue` in the tree and return its path if found, `null` otherwise.

The method below, simply tries to search for the node in a tree path, but it is just returning `undefined`, which I believe is due to async nature of the method. How do I rewrite the code to honour promises and get desired behaviour?

```
function searchNode(searchValue, path){
    tree.getChildren(path).then(function(children){
        if(children.length>0){
            for(var i = 0; i<children.length; i++){
                if(children[i] == searchValue){
                    return path;
                } else {
                    childPath = searchNode(searchValue, path+"/"+children[i]);
                    if(childPath != null)
                        return childPath;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: the function `searchNode` isn't returning anything

Comment: `getChildren`'s `then` promise will always return something, however delayed. I am not able to tie the future return value of `getChildren` to present return value of `searchNode`

Comment: i think the main problem lies in that `else` block where the code to return `childPath` is not waiting for the recursive call to `searchNode` to complete

Comment: It should be like `searchNode(searchValue, path+"/"+children[i]).then(function(childPath){return childPath or null })`. But then again searchNode is not returning a promise yet, its trying to return a value which does not exist in present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the result becomes available asynchronously, the function *searchNode* will need to return a Promise.

But at two places you do not do this:

1. You should *return* the first call to `tree.getChildren`
2. The (recursive) return value of `searchNode` should be handled as a promise, yet you treat it as a synchronous result:

   ```
    childPath = searchNode(searchValue, path+"/"+children[i]);
    if (childPath != null) { // ...etc.
   ```

   This is not possible. The return value should be a promise, and so you would need to call the `then` method on it to get the return value.

As you need to iterate several, maybe all, of the children, you would get as many promises back. But you can and should only return one promise.

Although you could return `null` in case of not finding the value, it is in my opinion more in line with the idea of promises to produce a rejected promise in that case.

So you could get the result of the first of those promises and then if it resolves, return that promise, but if it rejects (i.e. not found) you should chain the next promise, and the next, ... until one resolves, and return that one. If none of them resolve, or there are no children, a rejected promise should be returned.

Here is the suggested code:

```
function searchNode(searchValue, path){
    return tree.getChildren(path).then(function(children){
        // First look for the value among the immediate children
        for(let i = 0; i<children.length; i++){
            if(children[i] == searchValue){
                return path;
            }
        }
    // Then look deeper
    return (function loop(i) {
        if (i >= children.length) {
            return Promise.reject("not found"); 
        } else { 
            // after asynchronous result comes in, either
            // continue the loop, or resolve with path
            return searchNode(searchValue, path+"/"+children[i])
                .catch(loop.bind(null, i+1));
        }
    })(0);
}
```

```js
"use strict";
// Simple implementation of tree
const tree = {
    root: {
        '2': {
            '4': {
                '1': {}
            },
            '7': {}
        },
        '0': {}
    },
    getChildren: function(path) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            const node = path.split('/').reduce(function (parent, node) {
                return node === '' || !parent ? parent : parent[node];
            }, tree.root);
            resolve(Object.keys(node));
        });
    }
};

function searchNode(searchValue, path){
    return tree.getChildren(path).then(function(children){
        // First look for the value in the immediate children
        for(let i = 0; i<children.length; i++){
            if(children[i] == searchValue){
                return path;
            }
        }
        // Then look deeper
        return (function loop(i) {
            if (i >= children.length) {
                return Promise.reject("not found"); 
            } else { 
                // after asynchronous result comes in, either
                // continue the loop, or resolve with path
                return searchNode(searchValue, path+"/"+children[i])
                    .catch(loop.bind(null, i+1));
            }
        })(0);
    })
}

// Demo
searchNode('1', '').then(function (path) {
    console.log(path);
}, function (reason) {
    console.log(reason);
});
```

### A Parallel search alternative

The above solution will not look among the children in parallel. Instead it will wait for the search result for one node before deciding whether the search should be launched for the next sibling node. Depending on how asynchronous the `tree.getChildren` implementation really is, this may be inefficient:

Imagine a tree where the first child node has a multi-level sub-tree of 1000 nodes, while the value being looked for is an immediate descendant of the second child node. If the search would be launched in parallel, you'd expect the result sooner for such a scenario. On the other hand, the above code will not search other sibling nodes once the value has been found, while with a parallel search the search would continue in the "background" (asynchronously) even after the value has been found and the main promise is resolved. So we should make sure that no deeper searches are initiated when the value has been found.

In order to implement this parallel search idea you would launch *searchNode* on all children immediately, and apply the `then` method on each to monitor which one resolves as the first.

For this you could in fact define two generic utility methods -- `Promise.not` and `Promise.some` --, much like there already are `Promise.race` and `Promise.all`. These functions can be found in other Q&A like ["Resolve ES6 Promise with first success?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234191/resolve-es6-promise-with-first-success/37235274#37235274):

```
// Invert the outcome of a promise
Promise.not = promise => promise.then(x => {throw x}, e => e);
// Resolve when the first promise resolves
Promise.some = iterable => Promise.not(Promise.all(iterable.map(Promise.not)));
```

Or, you could use a library solution for this, like [bluebird's `Promise.any`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html).

Then, you would need to add some mechanism to stop initiating deeper searches when the main promise has already been resolved with the found value. For this it suffices to listen to the main promise and flag when it resolves. This can be used to stop the asynchronous code to initiate any further searches.

Here is how you would use that `Promise.some` function in your case:

```
function searchNode(searchValue, path){
    let resolved = false;

    return (function searchNodeSub(path) {
        return tree.getChildren(path).then(function(children){
            // If we already found the value via another parallel search, quit
            return resolved ? true
                // Otherwise look for the value among the immediate children
                : children.some(child => child == searchValue) ? path
                // If not found there, look deeper -- in parallel
                : Promise.some(children.map(child => searchNodeSub(path+"/"+child)));
        })
    })(path).then( path => (resolved = true, path) ); // register that we have a result
}
```

Note the similarity between `children.some` and `Promise.some`.

```js
"use strict";
// Simple implementation of tree
const tree = {
    root: {
        '2': {
            '4': {
                '1': {}
            },
            '7': {}
        },
        '0': {}
    },
    getChildren: function(path) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            let node = path.split('/').reduce(function (parent, node) {
                return node === '' || !parent ? parent : parent[node];
            }, tree.root);
            resolve(Object.keys(node));
        });
    }
};

// Invert the outcome of a promise
Promise.not = promise => promise.then(x => {throw x}, e => e);
// Resolve when the first promise resolves
Promise.some = iterable => Promise.not(Promise.all(iterable.map(Promise.not)));

function searchNode(searchValue, path){
    let resolved = false;
    
    return (function searchNodeSub(path) {
        return tree.getChildren(path).then(function(children){
            // If we already found the value via another parallel search, quit
            return resolved ? true
                // Otherwise look for the value among the immediate children
                : children.some(child => child == searchValue) ? path
                // If not found there, look deeper -- in parallel
                : Promise.some(children.map(child => searchNodeSub(path+"/"+child)));
        })
    })(path).then( path => (resolved = true, path) ); // register that we have a result
}

// Demo
searchNode('1', '').then(function (path) {
    console.log(path);
}, function (reason) {
    console.log('Not found');
});
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for highlighting that. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, though you probably didn't mean to pass the string `path` as a callback. Either pass `null` to `then` or just use `catch`

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi, indeed that non-function argument did not do anything useful. Replaced with `catch`.

Comment: @Bergi, I added an alternative to my answer, which *does* use a promise constructor to find the resolution, but I think in this case it is inevitable to achieve the desired outcome. I would appreciate if you would look into it at your convenience, and give your valuable feed-back.

Comment: Yeah, for writing a function such as `some` its OK to use the `Promise` constructor (though it *is* evitable, see [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37235274/1048572) [three](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21273983/1048572) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39941616/1048572)). However, **you should not write such functions on your own!** Use a library that provides them, such as [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html). Your solution avoided major problems, but still is troublesome. It doesn't work on iterators or non-iterables.

Comment: Wow, that is great info, @Bergi! I hope you don't mind I included it in my answer.

Comment: Attribute it to the author of the respective answer, not me :-) I certainly don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `.getChildren()` promise in `searchNode` so that you can later wait for it to resolve when returning the `childPath`:

```
function searchNode(searchValue, path){
  return tree.getChildren(path).then(function(children){ //return the promise so we can later wait for it to resolve
    if(children.length>0){
        for(var i = 0; i<children.length; i++){
            if(children[i] == searchValue){
                return path;
            } else {
                return searchNode(searchValue, path+"/"+children[i])
                  .then(function(childPath){ //wait for searchNode to complete
                    if (childPath != null) {
                      return childPath;
                    }
                  });
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: looks like its heading in the right direction. I can now write `searchNode(42, "/").then(function(value){console.log(value)})` which will wait for `.getChildren()` promise to resolve